Numerical Solution of Integral Equation with Integration Boundary Fixed by Equation Including Unknown Function
With Mathematica, I want to numerically solve an integral equation of the form
$$Z(\lambda)+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\Lambda}^{\Lambda}K(\lambda-\mu)Z(\mu)=1,$$
for $Z(x): \mathbb{R}↦\mathbb{R}$ where $K(x)$ is a known kernel function. The integral equation is thus similar to a Fredholm equation of second order, however $\Lambda$ is not fixed, but determined by the additional equation
$Z(\Lambda) = f(\Lambda)$, where $f$ is another known, fairly simple function.
I am new to integral equations and have so far looked at the numerous answers dealing with them here (e.g. this) and read up on Fredholm integral equations (in particular the Liouville–Neumann series). I also noticed replacing $\lambda$ by $\Lambda$ in the above would give something similar to a Volterra integral equation, which could then be solved and set equal to $f(\Lambda)$ to solve for $\Lambda$ - however again here, the lower limit in a Volterra integral equation is fixed as opposed to the form here. So I am wondering how this type of problem could be tackled in Mathematica?
(For completeness and specificity if relevant: $K(\lambda)=\frac{\sin(2\gamma)}{\cosh(\lambda)-\cos(2\gamma)}$, $f(\Lambda)=\frac{\pi  \sin(\gamma ) \text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi \Lambda }{2 \gamma }\right)}{4 \gamma  h}$ where $0<\gamma<\pi$ and $h \in \mathbb{R}^+$)

Please specify the values of all constants, without which a numerical solution cannot be obtained.

Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign, and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Function f[\[CapitalLambda]] is periodic, that means equation Z[\[CapitalLambda]]==f[\[CapitalLambda]] has multible solutions. Which solution is the one to choose as integration range?

Which article did you get this equation from?

@bbgodfrey Apologies for being unclear! I was ultimately aiming to solve the equation for different values of $\gamma, h$ to plot how the solution changes and was hoping for a method that works on a wide range of these parameters, but to be more specific $\gamma=2\pi/3, h = 0.125$ would be among the most interesting points in parameter space. (In case it helps to limit the interval range, from the underlying physics the most relevant part of the parameters would be $\pi/2 < \gamma < \pi$ and $0 < h < (1+\cos(\gamma))/2$).

@UlrichNeumann Apologies if I misunderstand, but I think $f(\Lambda)$ is not periodic? (Did you maybe take the secans hyperbolicus for a secans?)

@AlexTrounev This sort of equation occurs a lot in the thermodynamic Bethe ansatz, which is a technique in physics to solve for properties of integrable quantum many-body systems when considering large system sizes. A classic reference is 'Quantum Inverse Scattering Method and Correlation Functions' by V. E. Korepin, N. M. Bogoliubov, A. G. Izergin (1993), where this specific equation can be found in I. in different context for different models.

modified: f[u] corrected, h=1/8,\[Gamma]=2Pi/3
Perhaps NestList solves your problem iteratively!
Try
h = 1/8;  (* examplary parameter value*)
\[Gamma] =2 Pi/3;(* examplary parameter value*)
f = Function[u,Evaluate[Pi/(4 \[Gamma] h) Sin[\[Gamma]]/Cosh[(Pi u)/(2 \[Gamma])]]]
K = Function[u, Evaluate[ Sin[2 \[Gamma]]/(Cosh[u] - Cos[2 \[Gamma]])]]

grid = Subdivide[-1, 1, 20] ;

We start iteration with sample function 1+#^2& and try to solve equation Z[\[CapitalLambda]]==f[\[CapitalLambda]] for 0<\[CapitalLambda] 
fi = NestList[Function[fa, Block[{int, lambda, \[Lambda]i},
    lambda = 
      Values@FindRoot[
         fa[\[CapitalLambda]] == 
          f[\[CapitalLambda]] , {\[CapitalLambda], Pi/4, 0, 
          Pi/4}] [[1]]; ;
    mini = 
     NMinimize[{( fa[\[CapitalLambda]] - f[\[CapitalLambda]])^2, 
       0 < \[CapitalLambda]  }, \[CapitalLambda] ] ;
    lambda = Values@mini  [[2, 1]] ;
    int[\[Lambda]_?NumericQ] := 
     Block[{\[Mu]}, 
      1/(2 Pi) NIntegrate[ 
        K[\[Lambda] - \[Mu]] fa[\[Mu]], {\[Mu], -lambda, lambda}, 
        Method -> {{Automatic, "LocalAdaptive"}[[-1]], 
          "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]];
    \[Lambda]i = Flatten[Rationalize[lambda grid, 0], 1];
     Interpolation[
     Table[{\[Lambda]ii, 
       1 - int[\[Lambda]ii]}, {\[Lambda]ii, \[Lambda]i}]]]], 
  1 + #^2 &, 10];

Iteration converges
fi[[-1]]["Domain"][[1]] (*integration range*)

Plot[{Through[fi[[-3 ;;]][x]]}, {x, -%[[-1]], %[[-1]]}, 
AxesLabel -> {\[Lambda], "Z[\[Lambda]]"}]   (*last three iterations*)


Hope it helps!

Why in your plot you show $K[\lambda]$?

@AlexTrounev Ups, sould be Z, I'll change my answer, thanks

Thank you (+1).

Thank you very much, this is extremely helpful! I switched out the $\cos$ in f for a $\cosh$ and increased the limit for $\Lambda$ to allow for large values (re the comment above about the periodicity), which then seems to work at many values of $\gamma, h$ that I tested so far. There are some issues near the boundaries of the $[\pi/2, \pi]$ interval, where I am testing at the moment if having a finite grid / more iterations / etc. could help.

@lm1909 I don't understand what changed in the definition of f , please give some hint in your question. What is the limit of  Λ?

@UlrichNeumann The definition of $f$ did not change (the edit of the question was just to make it more readable). In your comment, you assumed that $f(\Lambda)$ is periodic - however, I think this is because you mistook the secans hyperbolicus for a secans in the definition of $f$. This is why in your answer in the definition of f you divide by Cos[(Pi u)...], which to correct, I changed to Cosh. Then $f$ is not periodic however, so the assumption that $\Lambda < \pi/4$ is not true. (tbc)

@UlrichNeumann Thus I changed this limit to a very large value (in NMinimize, NSolve) such that it contains the correct $\Lambda$ (which can become very large, indeed tends to $\infty$ for $h \rightarrow \infty$). From what I can tell at the moment, this continues to converge and work well, except for some corners of the $\gamma, h$ parameter space where the function becomes very large etc. Sorry for the confusion and thank you again, it has been immensely helpful!

@lm1909 See my modified answer

We can solve this problem using FDM. Results look same as in Ulrich answer.
sols[h_, \[Gamma]_] := Module[{L = 1, dx = .1},
  f[x_] := 
   Pi/(4  \[Gamma]  h)  Sin[\[Gamma]]/Cos[(Pi  x)/(2  \[Gamma])];
  K0[x_] := Sin[2  \[Gamma]]/(Cosh[x] - Cos[2  \[Gamma]]); 
  X = Range[-L, L, dx]; np = Length[X]; Z = Array[zz, np];
  eq = Table[
    Z[[k]] + 
     Lambda  dx /(2  Pi) Sum[(K0[
            X[[k]] - Lambda  X[[j]] + $MachineEpsilon]*Z[[j]] + 
          K0[ X[[k]] - 
             Lambda  X[[j + 1]] + $MachineEpsilon] Z[[j + 1]])/2, {j, 
        np - 1}] - 1, {k, np}]; y[0] = 1; 
  sol[0] = 
   FindRoot[Table[eq[[i]] == 0 /. Lambda -> y[0], {i, np}], 
    Table[{Z[[i]], .1}, {i, np}]];
  z[0] = Interpolation[Transpose[{X, Z /. sol[0]}]]; 
  Do[sol[i] = 
    FindRoot[
     Join[Table[
       eq[[i]] == 0, {i, np}], {f[Lambda] - z[i - 1][Lambda] == 0}], 
     Join[Table[{Z[[i]], .1}, {i, np}], {{Lambda, .1}}]]; 
   y[i] = Lambda /. sol[i]; 
   z[i] = Interpolation[Transpose[{X, Z /. sol[i]}]]; 
   If[Abs[y[i] - y[i - 1]] < 10^-6, Break[], Continue[]], {i, 10}];]

Example of usage
sols[1, Pi/4] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{0.852881, Null}*) 

Visualization
{ListLinePlot[Table[y[i], {i, 9}], PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Number of iterations", "\[CapitalLambda]"}], 
 Plot[z[9][x], {x, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"\[Lambda]", "Z"}]}


Parameter $\Lambda$
Table[y[i], {i, 9}]
{0.222501, 0.358274, 0.335847, 0.339617, 0.338985, 0.339091, \
0.339073, 0.339076, 0.339075}


Where do you adapt the integration range?

@UlrichNeumann See parameter Lambda in eq definition, and additional equation f[Lambda] - z[i - 1][Lambda] == 0 and variable Lambda in FindRoot in Do loop.

Thanks,I was unsure because of the plot V[\[Lambda]] with plot range -1,1

@UlrichNeumann This does not matter since function Z[x] is defined on an infinite interval.
